# How to use uwsgi to start multiple processes of the program on different gpu device？

Tags: deep-learning, uwsgi

I'm not familiar with uwsgi. When I use uwsgi to start a deep learning model service,the multiple processes started can only be started on the same GPU. How can I start multiple processes evenly on different GPUs? Can this be achieved by configuring the uwsgi.ini file? For example,use  GPU device-id as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

uwsgi.worker_id() function is used to obtain the ID of the current worker process.

```
import os,uwsgi    
worker_id = uwsgi.worker_id()
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = str(worker_id % num_gpu)
```